# Java API to make an object from a CSV file

Tags: java, csv

I'm looking for a library that allows me to map a .csv contents to an object.

Something like:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    @CsvField("name")
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @CsvField("age")
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

and then say something like:

```
final Person filledWithDataFromCsv = csvApi.load(csvFilepath, Person.class);
```

from the given CSV:

```
#name, age
tom, 11
jim, 32
```

Does anyone know of such an API, or one that does something similar. I don't want it to use annotations as a must, I just want to be able to load the file with one line of code and a predefined class.

Comment: It should be pretty easy to write one, however something which does it already would be better. I wouldn't use annotations either, I would just use the field names. ;)

Comment: I do not think that exists, however I could be wrong

Comment: @Peter why do you prefer field names over annotations ? I always tend to turn away from the reflection based approaches.

Comment: @Simeon, You would have to use reflections to get the annotations. Do the annotations add value, otherwise they just make your code more verbose?

Comment: @Peter well they decouple your field names from the csv, so you can rename freely. Otherwise if you decide that a new name better fits a given field, but you have already given your CSV format to a client you can no longer change your object member names (not without savage hacking anyway ...) :)

Comment: @simeon With annotations won't you need to tag your setter fields as well as your getter fields?

Comment: @Simeon, If you make that change you are better off defining the mapping externally, other wise you can only have one mapping for all versions of a file type ever.

Comment: @Peter hmm, agreed. I think I'm convinced :)

Comment: @Atreys no, you can either tag setters, getters or fields depending on preference. Hibernate/JPA uses the getters.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[JSefa](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/index.html) allow you to annotate Java classes that can be used in a serialization and de-serialization process. The [tutorial](http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/quick-tutorial.html) demonstrates how this works with the CsvIOFactory class.

(From the tutorial) Annotating a bean is as simple as specifying the locations of the items in the list of values, and if necessary, you'll need to specify the conversion format:

```
@CsvDataType()
public class Person {
    @CsvField(pos = 1)
    String name;

    @CsvField(pos = 2, format = "dd.MM.yyyy")
    Date   birthDate;
}
```

Comment: @VineetReynolds can we use it without postion, i mean with the help of columnName?

Answer (score 12):

I prefer `opencsv`, it is ultra simple and very clean.

http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/

For example reading:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
}
```

Comment: Your example does not map to a java bean with annotations.

Comment: See here for how to do it with open csv http://stackoverflow.com/a/14976689/1000011

Comment: + one to this, opencsv is more up to date as of 2020

Answer (score 11):

You can't go wrong with [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial). It supports all sorts of powerful operations and it is much faster than any other CSV parser for Java.

Here's a class with some examples:

```
class TestBean {

    // if the value parsed in the quantity column is "?" or "-", it will be replaced by null.
    @NullString(nulls = { "?", "-" })
    // if a value resolves to null, it will be converted to the String "0".
    @Parsed(defaultNullRead = "0")
    private Integer quantity;   // The attribute type defines which conversion will be executed when processing the value.

    @Trim
    @LowerCase
    // the value for the comments attribute is in the column at index 4 (0 is the first column, so this means fifth column in the file)
    @Parsed(index = 4)
    private String comments;

    // you can also explicitly give the name of a column in the file.
    @Parsed(field = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Trim
    @LowerCase
    // values "no", "n" and "null" will be converted to false; values "yes" and "y" will be converted to true
    @BooleanString(falseStrings = { "no", "n", "null" }, trueStrings = { "yes", "y" })
    @Parsed
    private Boolean pending;
}
```

Here's how to get a list of `TestBean`

```
BeanListProcessor<TestBean> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<TestBean>(TestBean.class);

CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.setRowProcessor(rowProcessor);
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
parser.parse(getReader("/examples/bean_test.csv"));

List<TestBean> beans = rowProcessor.getBeans();
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Comment: `getReader` is not defined?

Comment: Just use new FileReader(new File("path/to/file.csv"));

Comment: Can  JeronimoBackes or @josliber answer this one please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36647873/need-to-map-multiple-columnames-to-a-single-field-in-univocity

Comment: I see an Apache License version of the project at https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/# but see an entirely different site that talks about it being free for non-commerical use http://www.univocity.com/products/license  Can you clarify the differences between the Apache version and the version on the univocity.com site?

Comment: Univocity-parsers is free. The univocity framework is commercial.

Comment: @JeronimoBackes i was trying to use it but  readOrder was null for me at BeanConversionProcessor - and  
rowProcessor.getBeans() came back as null. what can i do to fix it ?

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the best answer, especially the `map field by header name` feature. I can't find the same feature in other CSV parser.

Comment: This seriously needs to be voted up.  I spent all day trying to use JSEFA pulling my hair out trying to get it to work, and then I found this and had it running like clockwork  within 10 minutes!  Thank you for your great work!

Answer (score 4):

There are pretty good JDBC implementations for CSV. So you can make use of such a driver, configure a datasource to use it and then use JPA (or whatever) for object-relational mapping on top of that data source.

Answer (score 3):

[SimpleFlatMapper](https://simpleflatmapper.org/) can do that easily 
see [Getting Started csv](https://simpleflatmapper.org/0101-getting-started-csv.html#mapping-a-csv-to-an-object) using the headers of the csv or by manually specifying which columns map to what property.

```
CsvParser
    .mapTo(MyObject.class)
    .forEach(file, System.out::println);
```