# Using captureHeader in OpenCSV

Tags: java, opencsv

Perhaps I am not understanding what the method captureHeader() in OpenCSV is for, but the method grabs a CSV file's headers and sets a protected 'header' variable to a String array of those values.

But then how do you access those header values to try and match say "first_name" from the csv to "firstName" in your Bean? The idea being to create the MappingStrategy from those headers before actually parsing the full csv file. However captureHeader() is a void and 'header' is protected?

[OpenCSV API](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/bean/HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy.html)

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement the `captureHeader` method and store the `string[] header` in a list. You can now iterate through this list and map according to your bean.

Example:

```
public void captureHeader(CSVReader reader){
    super.captureHeader(reader);
    List<String> csvHeader = Arrays.asList(header);
    //iterate through the list
    }
```

You could also use `HeaderColumnNameTranslateMappingStrategy` for your task. Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505653/opencsv-how-to-map-selected-columns-to-java-bean-regardless-of-order/14976689#14976689).