# OpenCSV convert csv to nested bean

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

We are using OpenCSV. The csv is as

```
id,fname,lname,address.line1,address.line2
```

The beans are

```
Person{
  String id;
  String lname;
  String fname;
  Address address;
}

Address{
  String line1;
  String line2;  
}
```

Is it possible to fill the nested `Address` object with opencsv !
The `opencsv.bean` and `opencsv.bean.customconverter` have some classes which seems can do what I want but I could not find any samples.

I have seen the 
[Parse CSV to multiple/nested bean types with OpenCSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111296/parse-csv-to-multiple-nested-bean-types-with-opencsv) but the answer focus on SuperCSV, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this ?

Comment: Also interested

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a custom [MappingStrategy](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/MappingStrategy.html) class and implement the method [populateNewBean(...)](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/MappingStrategy.html#populateNewBean-java.lang.String:A-) providing you means to populate beans as you like.

See this example:

```
public void example() {
    Reader in = new StringReader(
            "1,Doe,John,123 Main St,\"Anytown, USA\"\n" +
            "2,Dean,James,111 Some St,\"Othertown, USA\"\n" +
            "3,Burger,Sam,99 Beach Avenue,\"Sometown, USA\"\n");
    CsvToBeanBuilder<Person> builder = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Person>(in)
            .withMappingStrategy(new PersonMappingStrategy());
    CsvToBean<Person> ctb = builder.build();
    for (Person person : ctb.parse()) {
        System.out.println(
                person.id
                + "\t" + person.lname
                + "\t" + person.fname
                + "\t" + person.address.line1
                + "\t" + person.address.line2);
    }
}

class Person {
    String id;
    String lname;
    String fname;
    Address address;
}

class Address {
    String line1;
    String line2;  
}

class PersonMappingStrategy extends ColumnPositionMappingStrategy {

    public PersonMappingStrategy() {
        this.setType(Person.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object populateNewBean(String[] line) throws CsvBeanIntrospectionException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException,
    CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvConstraintViolationException, CsvValidationException {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.id = line[0];
        person.lname = line[1];
        person.fname = line[2];
        person.address = new Address();
        person.address.line1 = line[3];
        person.address.line2 = line[4];
        return person;
    }

}
```

The output is

```
1       Doe     John    123 Main St     Anytown, USA
2       Dean    James   111 Some St     Othertown, USA
3       Burger  Sam     99 Beach Avenue Sometown, USA
```

Comment: I need to do exact reverse. Can you put some example where nested bean is converted to csv? thanks.

Comment: @ Saurabhcdt, write [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it.

Answer (score 0):

In OpenCSV 5.0, we can map nested bean by `@CsvRecurse` annotation. Documentation as follow

> Instructs a mapping strategy to look inside a member variable for
>   further mapping annotations.

please check [OpenCSV: Mapping a Nested Bean to a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289276/3268354)