# OpenCSV: Mapping a Nested Bean to a CSV file

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, opencsv

I am trying to map a bean to a CSV file but the problem that my bean has other nested beans as attributes. What happens is that OpenCSV goes through the attributes finds a bean then goes into it and maps all the data inside of that bean and if it finds another bean it goes on and on. How can I deal withe nested beans using OpenCSV? How can I ensure that it maps the correct attributes from the nested beans?

Comment: Is your problem in writing or in reading a nested bean? If reading, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250616/2158271).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In OpenCSV 5.0, we can map nested bean by `@CsvRecurse` annotation without using MappingStrategy.

> The ability to split mappings from input/output columns to member
>   variables of multiple embedded beans has been added through the
>   annotation @CsvRecurse. One root bean is still necessary.

Csv file

```
id,cardNumber,holder
1,1234567 890,abc
```

Root bean

```
public class DataSet {

    @CsvBindByName
    private String id;

    @CsvRecurse
    private MyNumber myNumber;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Nested bean

```
public class MyNumber {

    @CsvBindByName
    private String cardNumber;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String holder;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Reading beans

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("path-to-csv-file.csv"));
        List<DataSet> beans = new CsvToBeanBuilder<DataSet>(reader).withType(DataSet.class).build().parse();
    }
```

Ref: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#multivaluedmap_based_bean_fields_many_to_one_mappings

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for! Also found that SuperCSV supports it using Dozer.