# openCSV with complex bean structure

Tags: java, opencsv

I try to map a nested bean structure with openCSV. I found the [@CsvRecurse](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#recursion_into_subordinate_beans) annotation, but this does not seem to work if a nested bean is used multiple times.

What options do I have to solve this?

**Example** (adapted from the docs linked above)

Data structure to map :

```
title,author1 given name,author1 surname,author2 given name,author2 surname
Space Opera 2.0,Andrew,Jones,Hanna,Smith
```

I would like to get the following beans

```
public class Book {
    @CsvBindByName
    private String title;

    // TODO: How to bind author1 and author2?
    private Author author1;
    private Author author2;

    // Accessor methods go here.
}

public class Author {
    // TODO: can I somehow use a prefix/Regex for the column here to differentiate between author1 and author2?
    @CsvBindByName(column = "author[1/2] given name")
    private String givenName;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "author[1/2] surname")
    private String surname;

    // Accessor methods go here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom 'ColumnPositionMappingStrategy'. Override 'populateNewBean' method which takes String[] (row of csv) and can form any object out of it.

[Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59250616/10812004)

'@CsvRecurse' should work for Open OpenCSV 5.0 btw.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
I will check if a custom mapping strategy can solve my issue (but I will probably opt for ```HeaderNameBaseMappingStrategy``` since the order of the columns can change in the input). 
However, I would prefer to use ```@CsvRecurse```  if possible. But it does not seem to do what I need it to do: it only seems to apply to cases where there is max. 1 variable of the same class type, right? So it would work perfectly, if I had 1 ```Author``` variable. But is there a way to use it with 2 ```Author``` variables in my source bean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

The opencsv library has a lot of useful and flexible annotations, but in this specific case, I would not use any of them.

Instead, I would use the opencsv [`CSVReaderHeaderAware`](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVReaderHeaderAware.html) class. Using this will allow you to keep your two `Book` and `Author` classes. The only thing I would change is to add constructors to each class as follows:

Book:

```
public class Book {

    private final String title;
    private final Author author1;
    private final Author author2;

    public Book(String title, Author author1, Author author2) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author1 = author1;
        this.author2 = author2;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Author getAuthor1() {
        return author1;
    }

    public Author getAuthor2() {
        return author2;
    }

}
```

Author:

```
public class Author {

    private final String givenName;
    private final String surname;

    public Author(String givenName, String surname) {
        this.givenName = givenName;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getGivenName() {
        return givenName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

}
```

To populate a list of `Book` objects from a CSV file, do this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderHeaderAware;
import com.opencsv.exceptions.CsvValidationException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

...

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, 
            IOException, CsvValidationException {
        String bookFile = "/path/to/titles.csv";

        CSVReaderHeaderAware csvReader = new CSVReaderHeaderAware(new FileReader(bookFile));

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList();

        Map<String, String> bookRecord;
        while ((bookRecord = csvReader.readMap()) != null) {
            books.add(handleBook(bookRecord));
        }
    }

    private static Book handleBook(Map<String, String> bookRecord) {
        Author author1 = new Author(
                bookRecord.get("author1 given name"),
                bookRecord.get("author1 surname")
        );

        Author author2 = new Author(
                bookRecord.get("author2 given name"),
                bookRecord.get("author2 surname")
        );

        return new Book(bookRecord.get("title"), author1, author2);
    }
```

Each row of data from the CSV file is read into a `Map` object, where the file headers are the map's *keys* (you need make sure the file headers are unique). The Map's corresponding *values* represent one row of data from the CSV file.

The only downside to this is you may need to cast string values to other data types - although not in this case, because the data items are already strings.