# Opencsv, StatefulBeanToCsv write nested List of Objects to csv

Tags: java, list, csv, opencsv, writetofile

I have to write nested list of objects(StoreLocations) into Csv file using open csv. 
My model classes are-

```
public class StoreLocation {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private int zip;
    private String streetAndNumber;
    private List<String> keywords;
    private Double lat;
    private Double lng;
    private List<OpeningHours> openingHours;
}

public class OpeningHours {
    private String dayOfWeek;
    private String from1;
    private String to1;
}
```

My method to write-

```
public void getStoreLocationData(List<StoreLocation> storeLocations) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
        try (
                Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(storeLocationDataCsv))
        ) {
            StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
                    .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                    .build();
            beanToCsv.write(storeLocations);
        }
    }
```

This code generates all columns perfectly, except the list of opening hours.
This is the current output-[image]
I would prefer to either have a column of opening hours and arrange each opening hour as a new row.
Something like[image]
or having all opening hours in a json list inside opening hours column.
Probably I need columnPositionMappingStrategy to set these columns, but I need clue how to use it?

Here is the json representation of the List of array locations-

```
[{
"name":"OBI Markt Kempen",
"city":"Kempen",
"zip":47906,
"streetAndNumber":"Kleinbahnstraße 32",
"keywords":[],
"lat":51.3740233,
"lng":6.4182039,
"openingHours":
[{"dayOfWeek":"1","from1":"08:00","to1":"20:00"},
{"dayOfWeek":"2","from1":"08:00","to1":"20:00"},
]}]
```

Note: I tried using super csv () referring to [Parse CSV to multiple/nested bean types with OpenCSV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111296/parse-csv-to-multiple-nested-bean-types-with-opencsv) ,bur it makes pretty complicated and also I don't understand how to write it to the file.

Also I have referred all the articles for writing complex/nested java object to csv over stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomMappingStrategy<T> extends ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<T> {

    public String[] generateHeader() {
        
            return new String[]{"name","city","zip",
           "streetAndNumber" ,"keywords","lat","lon","openingHrs_dayOfWeek","openingHrs_froml","openingHrs_to1"
          
        };
        
    }
    
    //override transmuteBean  or toString() in StoreLocation
        @Override
    public String[] transmuteBean(T bean) {
        // Override this method to handle nested objects
        if (bean instanceof StoreLocation ) {
            return toStringArray((StoreLocation) bean);
        } else {
            
            return new String[0]; 
        }
    }
    
    
    public String[] toStringArray(StoreLocation storeLocation) {
        return new String[] {
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getName()),
        
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getCity()),
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getZip()),
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getStreeAndNumber()),
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getKeyWords().toString()),
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getLat()),
                String.valueOf(storeLocation.getLon()),
                List<OpeningHours> openingHours = storeLocation.getOpeningHrs();
                for(OpeningHours obj: openingHours)
                { 
                String.valueOf(obj.getDayOfWeek()),
                String.valueOf(obj.getFrom1()),
                String.valueOf(obj.getTo1()),
                }
                
        
        };
    }
    
    }
    
    //use above strategy 
    
    public void getStoreLocationData(List<StoreLocation> storeLocations) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
    
      CustomMappingStrategy<StoreLocation> strategy = new CustomMappingStrategy<>();
        String[] headers=strategy.generateHeader();
        strategy.setType(StoreLocation.class);
        strategy.setColumnMapping(headers);
       
        try (
                Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(storeLocationDataCsv))
        ) {
            StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
                    .withMappingStrategy(mappingStrategy)
                    .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
                    .build();
            beanToCsv.write(storeLocations);
        }
    }
```