# Map CSV to Object, get data from Object afterwards

Tags: java, csv

Currently i'm trying to map a csv to a java object.

The headers should be:

```
CID,CName,SID,SName,Country,Street,StreetNumber,ZipCode,Number,IP,type,isAdmin
```

The actual CSV has no headers and looks like this:

```
1,RINT,00001,Foo,Bar,Street,1,1010,1,10.1.2.1,typeR,1
1,RINT,00001,Foo,Bar,Street,1,1010,2,10.1.2.2,typeL,0
1,RINT,00001,Foo,Bar,Street,1,1010,3,10.1.2.3,typeL,0
1,RINT,00001,Foo,Bar,Street,1,1010,4,10.1.2.4,typeL,0
2,RANT,00002,Foo,Bar,Street,2,1011,1,10.1.2.1,typeR,1
2,RANT,00002,Foo,Bar,Street,2,1011,2,10.1.2.2,typeL,0
2,RANT,00002,Foo,Bar,Street,2,1011,3,10.1.2.3,typeL,0
2,RANT,00002,Foo,Bar,Street,2,1011,4,10.1.2.4,typeL,0
```

While i have found out that i could map this with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505653/opencsv-how-to-map-selected-columns-to-java-bean-regardless-of-order/48227474#48227474). Ofc I'd first need a class called Sessions which looks like the csv sheet???

```
public class Sessions(){
  private integer cId;
  private String cName;
  private integer sId;
  private String sName;
  ....
}
```

I am a bit confused about how to get the data from the object to further process it (like: display in a GUI to let me select certain data and write putty sessions with this information -> .reg files OR .txt files).

The amount of sessions (each csv row) i have right now is around 1000 - 2000 and growing. They are exported via a trigger out of a database and then should be further processed by a java program (that i'm writing) to manage the amount of sessions for putty.

So how do i "read" the data from that Object (Session.class) again? Maybe im just dumb right now.

Comment: When you look at the thread you found, you see that it works with a `List`of `Session`. So you can iterate over the elements of the list.

Comment: So i was blind indeed. Thanks for pointing that out =). I solved my issued with and created a corresponding PuttySession class which contains the needed fields. 
 `Map<String, List<PuttySession>> allPuttySession = new HashMap<String, List<PuttySession>>();`