# How to use column mapping with BatchedColumnProcessor in univocity

Tags: java, csv, univocity

How can i use column mapping by using **BatchedColumnProcessor** in univocity?

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setProcessor(new BatchedColumnProcessor(5) {
        @Override
        public void batchProcessed(int rowsInThisBatch) {}
    });
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
```

like we use in **BeanListProcessor** and add custom column mapping

```
BeanListProcessor<Product> rowProcessor = new BeanListProcessor<Product>(Product.class);
rowProcessor.setColumnMapping();
```

Answer (score 0):

`setColumnMapping` is only mentioned once in [`univocity/univocity-parsers` issue 287](https://github.com/univocity/univocity-parsers/issues/287#issuecomment-436992466), and illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64050993/6309), applied to a `ColumnPositionMappingStrategy` with opencsv.

That issue mentions "[initial code to support github issue #287 - map column name to attribute](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/commit/65d3d59bdaf5b7cdad5e6d9fd3bdff9e5e20f16a)", with an example at [`Github_287.java`](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/blob/master/src/test/java/com/univocity/parsers/issues/github/Github_287.java)

So [from 2.8.0](https://github.com/univocity/univocity-parsers/issues/287#issuecomment-455440938):

> I've released a 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT build which allows you to call
> `getColumnMapper()` from:
>
> ```
> any *Routines class
> any *Bean*Processor class (including BeanWriterProcessor) for writing
>
> mapper.attributeToIndex("name", 0); //name goes to the first column
> mapper.attributeToColumnName("name", "client_name"); .// same thing, but the first column has header "client_name"
> ```
>
> Nested classes are also supported, you can do stuff such as the
> following, where name is buried in an object structure (assume a class
> Purchase with a `Buyer` attribute, which in turn has a `Contact`
> attribute, where the name is located):
>
> ```
> mapper.methodToIndex("buyer.contact.name", 0); 
>
> // use methods too. This assumes Contact has a `fullName(java.lang.String)` setter method:
> mapper.methodToColumnName("buyer.contact.fullName", String.class, "client_name");
>
> // this maps getter and setter methods named `fullName` to column `client_name`. The getters or setters are used depending if you are
> ```
>
> writing to a file or reading from it.
> mapper.methodToColumnName("buyer.contact.fullName", "client_name");
>
> You can also just give it a map:
>
> ```
> Map<String, Integer> mappings = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
> ... fill your map
> mapper.attributesToIndexes(mappings);
> ```