# serialize csv file into an object in jersey service

Tags: java, jersey, opencsv

i am trying to write a jersey service which consumes a CSV file. i want to serialize that csv file into an object. what can i do to achieve this? i am going to use opencsv as the parser library for csv file.

my base structure of the service:

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN){
        public void addUsers(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputStream) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{

    }
```

is the @Consumes annotation which i am using the right way as well?

Comment: Does this answer help ? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411357/java-api-to-make-an-object-from-a-csv-file

Comment: this does seem to help to serialize into objects. i am using similar annotations for XML so will just need to add into the class. 
am i using the correct @Consumes annotation for it ?

Comment: Are you uploading the CSV as a file ? Can you use a multipart upload instead ? CSV has it's own mime type as defined by [RFC4180](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) although I'm unaware if jersey distinguishes it. As long as you read the stream using the right encoding you should be good.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm going to move my comments to the answer section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer tells you how to convert CSV to an object in java - [Java API to make an object from a CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411357/java-api-to-make-an-object-from-a-csv-file)

Are you uploading the CSV as a file ? Can you use a multipart upload instead (if that makes sense. Multipart let's you consider the file upload as an attachment of sorts. Usually there is meta-data associated with such requests, which can be sent as a separate part) ? CSV has it's own mime type as defined by [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) although I'm unaware if jersey distinguishes it. As long as you read the stream using the right encoding you should be good.