# Need to map multiple columNames to a single field in Univocity

Tags: java, csv, annotations

```
class MyPOJO implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Parsed(field = "UniqueCode")
    private String            code;
    @Parsed(field = "Name")
    private String            name;
    @Parsed(field = "dogId")
    private String            someOtherId;


    //------Getters and Setters-------
    public String getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getSomeOtherId()
    {
        return someOtherId;
    }
    public void setSomeOtherId(String someOtherId)
    {
        this.someOtherId = someOtherId;
    }



}
```

Now I need to map a single field,for example someOtherId with multiple header Names (e.g: "dogId","catId","cowId" etc) coming from different csv files. So suppose in files **1.csv** the header column called `dogId` should map to POJO field `someOtherId` whereas in file **2.csv** the header `catId` should map to the same field i.e. `someOtherId`. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse this easily if the columns with values for `someOtherId` are always in the same location, no matter which files you are using.

```
class MyPOJO implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Parsed(field = "UniqueCode")
    private String            code;
    @Parsed(field = "Name")
    private String            name;
    @Parsed(index = 2) //anything goes here, "catId", "cowId", etc
    private String            someOtherId;

    ...
}
```

If the column position varies in each input file, you could implement your own row processor. I created the following implementation that will probably work for you. It essentially maps possible headers to an index. These indexes should match with the indexes annotated in your class.

I'll break the details down to help you understand what I did.

#### First assign an index to each field of your POJO:

```
    @Parsed(index = 0)
    private String code;
    @Parsed(index = 1)
    private String name;
    @Parsed(index = 2) //cowId, dogId or catId or anything else
    private String someOtherId;
```

#### Create a wrapper around the existing BeanProcessor implementation:

```
public class MyBeanProcessor<T> extends AbstractRowProcessor{
    //here's the wrapped bean processor.
    private final BeanListProcessor<T> processor;

    //we need a LinkedHashMap here to keep the the correct ordering.
    private final LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> headersToCapture;

    public MyBeanProcessor(Class<T> beanType, LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> headersToCapture){
        processor = new BeanListProcessor<T>(beanType);
        this.headersToCapture = headersToCapture;
    }

    // work with parsed headers to find out what is in the input
    @Override
    public void rowProcessed(String[] inputRow, ParsingContext context) {
        //... more details later
    }

    @Override
    public void processEnded(ParsingContext context) {
        processor.processEnded(context);
    }

    public List<T> getBeans(){
        return processor.getBeans();
    }
}
```

## Intended usage of this custom row processor:

```
//keys are possible headers, and values are the indexes where each header will be mapped to:
Map<String, Integer> headerPositions = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();
headerPositions.put("UniqueCode", 0);
headerPositions.put("Name", 1);
headerPositions.put("dogId", 2);
headerPositions.put("catId", 2);
headerPositions.put("cowId", 2);

CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
//we want headers
settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

//let's use the custom row processor:
MyBeanProcessor<MyPOJO> processor = new MyBeanProcessor<MyPOJO>(MyPOJO.class, headerPositions);
settings.setRowProcessor(processor);

CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
parser.parse(<YOUR_INPUT_HERE>);

List<MyPOJO> myPojos = processor.getBeans();
```

#### Implementation of the `rowProcessed` method:

```
    private int[] headerIndexes = null;
    private String[] row = null;

    @Override
    public void rowProcessed(String[] inputRow, ParsingContext context) {
        if(headerIndexes == null){ //initializes the indexes to capture
            processor.processStarted(context);
            String[] parsedHeaders = context.headers();

            LinkedHashSet<Integer> indexes = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
            for(String headerToCapture : headersToCapture.keySet()){
                int headerIndex = ArgumentUtils.indexOf(parsedHeaders, headerToCapture);
                if(headerIndex != -1){
                    indexes.add(headerIndex);
                }
            }
            headerIndexes = ArgumentUtils.toIntArray(indexes);
            row = new String[indexes.size()]; //creates a reusable row with the number of columns captured
        }

        //once the input format is known, we can collect the values from the expected positions:
        for(int i = 0; i < headerIndexes.length; i++){
            int indexToCapture = headerIndexes[i];
            if(indexToCapture < inputRow.length){
                row[i] = inputRow[indexToCapture];
            } else {
                row[i] = null;
            }
        }
        //and submit a row with the values in the correct places to the actual bean processor
        processor.rowProcessed(row, context);
    }
```

I tested this locally and the following inputs are parsed as expected, no matter where the headers are located:

#### Input 1

```
UniqueCode,T,name,dogId
1,99,2,3
```

Produces

```
MyPOJO{code='1', name='2', someOtherId='3'}
```

#### Input 2

```
cowId,Z,UniqueCode,T,name
4,99,5,99,6
```

Produces

```
MyPOJO{code='5', name='6', someOtherId='4'}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately the index is not in the same column always..but I think the custom row processor will work..checking

Comment: Works but with a few glitches like the already annotated fields if not put in the  headerPositions map does not show up inspite of having  settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);

Comment: It would be great if the annotation  @Parsed(field = "<somevalue>") could just take some comma separated fields as this is a real scenario where a POJO is used to map multiple fields from different CSVs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see if I can create built-in support for this in version 2.1.0. Please accept the answer if you think it helped to solve your problem. All the best!